# when executing "import pyodbc" in python 3.6 (anaconda3) Jupyter Notebook throws error: ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

What I want to accomplish:

- execute *import pyodbc* statement within Jupyter Notebook and thus use pyodbc to import data from sql databases such as SQL Server,  Exasol, etc.

What is the environment:

- Anaconda3 (py36_0) installed on Windows 10 - 64 bit Version
- pyodbc installed via conda (*conda install pyodbc*) -> this worked as *conda list* shows that pyodbc 4.0.16 py36_0 is installed
- jupyter notebook works, for example *import pandas* works fine

What happens:

- after issuing the command *import pyodbc* within the jupyter notebook, the following error message appears:

  ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
   in ()
  ----> 1 import pyodbc
  ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.

Thanks in advance for any helpful answer!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I don't think Anaconda is compatible with the latest pyodbc version.  (see their website: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs which lists version 3.0.10 support for python 3.6)

I was able to solve this by downgrading my package using this command:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyodbc=3.0.10
```

This worked for me in my tests.  Hope this helps.  Please let me know if it does!

Comment: Downgrading the package to this version (3.0.10) corrected the error in my testing.

Comment: This resolution helped. Thanks in particular pointing out the website which lists the supported packages per python version. I wonder whyconda install pyodbc recommends installing a version that is obviously incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

After translating the German error message, it appears you haven't installed `pyodbc` with Anaconda:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyodbc=3.0.10
```

That should solve your immediate problem, however, there may be some other tweaks to do to get `pyodbc` to run on Windows.

Comment: pyodbc was installed, solution is to downgrade pyodbc version. When pyodbc is not installed the error message is `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dbc27c5f2947> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyodbc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'`

Answer (score 1):

Updating pyodbc from 4.0.16-py36_0 to 4.0.17-py36_0 resolved the issue for me.

I ran the following conda command from the command line.

```
conda update pyodbc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

Go to https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyodbc/files

And download https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyodbc/3.0.10/download/win-64/pyodbc-3.0.10-py36_1.tar.bz2

In this adress \Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages you look for the pyodbc.pyd and the .eggs-info file, you replace those files for the same file of the 3.0.10 version that is in the pyodbc-3.0.10-py36_1.tar.bz2.

That worked for me. Hope it also work for you