# pyodbc ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could > not be found

Tags: python, pyodbc

When trying to import pyodbc i get the below error.  How do I resolve this?  All other things I have found on here has not worked.  I have also tried everything on this site: https://medium.com/@mauridb/how-to-check-your-anaconda-version-c092400c9978 when it comes to updating the anaconda version (which has only been installed for 30 days on this computer).

I have also tried the below code, and I still get the same error on import.  Any assistance would be great.

```
pip install pyodbc --force-reinstall
```

I am using:

Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Spyder 4.0.1 from Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7 on a windows 10 PC

> import pyodbc ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could
>   not be found.

Comment: in your console (cmd) work? ..

Comment: The command reinstalled yes but the problem remained.

Comment: Have you tried downgrading the version following this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076036/12532130 ?

Comment: Hi Jason, I have tried downgrading as well.  It did not work.

Comment: This issue was fixed in pyodbc 4.0.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pypyodbc package worked instead.  The connection strings are the same as pyodbc.  Call the SQL code with:

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc

conn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver'={SQL Server};' 
                        'Server=Server;' 
                        'Database=database;
                        'Trusted_Connection=yes;') 

pd.read_sql_query('''SQL CODE''', conn)
```

It was very important to not use any pace in the connection string where the equal (=) signs are.  Not sure why this is.

Comment: pypyodbc is no longer being actively developed or supported. A better solution is to use pyodbc with the latest version of the Microsoft C++ redistributable package. More details [on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/663#issuecomment-569365502).

Comment: This did not work, though it was something I had not tried.  Thank you for letting me know that pypyodbc is outdated.  I will need to figure this out then.

Comment: Failure to load a DLL is often because the DLL is a different bitness (32-bit vs 64-bit) from the interpreter. It is easy to have 2 versions of Python installed without being aware of it, and if you do, i is likely that the `pip` you are running is a different bitness from thee interpreter. Just invoking `pip` from the command line means that you are getting whichever one is first in the path.

Comment: @BoarGules, can you please inform on how one would go about checking for this and correcting this?

Comment: You can find out if you have more than one copy of `pip.exe` using the command `where pip`. Navigate to the folder where the installation of Python that you are expecting to use lives. This will normally be `Python3x`. Then go to its `Scripts` subfolder. The `pip.exe` in that folder is the correct one for the installation, which may not be the one you get when you just type `pip` at the command line. To find out what that command line does, type `pip --version`. It will tell you the version of `pip`, its location on disk, and which version of Python it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and work to me when I installed the latest supported Visual C++. You can do a download in link bellow: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

I found this solution from the link bellow, where other people had the problem too.
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/663