# import pyodc in docker failing

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pyodbc

I am using a windows docker. I have added pyodbc in requirements.txt. Again i have added a separate command to install pyodbc Python explicitly. Still I am getting errors while running the docker image. What should be correct way to import all the modules mentioned in requirements.txt

Commands I have in docker file:-

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

ENV PYTHONPATH /code

COPY ./tools/installers/msodbcsql_17.4.2.1_x64.msi ./msodbcsql_17.4.2.1_x64.msi

RUN Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I msodbcsql_17.4.2.1_x64.msi /norestart /qn 
 IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES'


RUN pip install pyodbc

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

I am getting below errors:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./main.py", line 7, in <module>
from azure_resources.database import Database
  File "C:\code\azure_resources\database.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyodbc
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyodbc ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could > not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687910/pyodbc-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Comment: No , This Doesn't. My question is more related to Docker so.. my code running well in local system but failing in docker.

Comment: Try `RUN pip install pyodbc==4.0.27` instead of `RUN pip install pyodbc`

Comment: ODBC requires an underlying driver to connect to the database.  Which driver are you using in your connection string to your database?

Comment: Thanks Gord Thompson it worked. But why this version issue with Docker? If i dont specify the version then Docker pulls the latest(pyodbc 4.0.28). Right?

Comment: Yes, and that's the same issue I cited in my first comment. This really is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687910/pyodbc-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found). See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/663) for details.